# Creating a custom profile with "column username is not unique error"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-allauth

I'm trying to extend the basic user profile in Django-allauth. The signup form loads correctly, but after submitting the form there's a **"column username is not unique error"**.

The project files are as below:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
    has_accepted_tos = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                            verbose_name='I accept site rules')
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['has_accepted_tos']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

    User.profile = property(lambda u:UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import UserProfile
from django.forms import CharField, BooleanField, ModelForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter

# forms.py

    class SignupForm(ModelForm):

        has_accepted_tos = BooleanField(error_messages={'required': _('You must accept the terms and conditions')}, 
                                            label=_('I accept site terms and conditions'), 
                                            required=True)

        class Meta:
            #model = get_user_model
            model = UserProfile
            fields = ('website', 'picture', 'has_accepted_tos') 

        def signup(self, request, user):
            adapter = get_adapter()
            user = adapter.new_user(request)
            adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
```

I'm suspecting that signup method is not implemented correctly. Can someone advise?

Comment: The obvious thing to check is that the username doesn't already exist in the database. I assume you checked that? It happens with every name you try to enter?